# Is the baseUrl is per User or per Account?

Tags: docusignapi

Is the baseUrl value returned per user or can it be used by all future users of the same account? I want to cache this value and as far as I can tell this is actually an account setting even though it's only retrieved after a user specific login. Any chance two users of the same account could have a different baseUrl? Just want to know at what level i really need to cache this.

thanks,
-mike

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to cache it? Is the call to LoginInformation taking an especially long amount of time? Why not call it each time as the docs suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is Per Account

> Is the baseUrl value returned per user or can it be used by all future
>   users of the same account?

---

## restapi/v{#}/login_information

This call will give you back the list of accounts that the username/password has access to. Along with the list of accounts, you'll receive the `baseUrl` for that account.

### `baseUrl` defines two things:

1. The server that the account resides on
2. The account number

If there is a specific account that you're going to add users to, the `baseUrl` will be the same for future users of that account.

### If you do not have multiple accounts logging into your application.

You can cache the information from this call so you don't have it in every workflow. It is mostly used for setting up new workflows and moving between Demo and Production.

### If you do have multiple accounts logging into your application.

I would advise that you call this information at the start of your workflow. It'll ensure that you're calling the correct account for that user.

One thing to keep in mind, that 1 set of username / password can have access to multiple accounts. So you may receive more than 1 array as a response, your application should handle this accordingly.

Comment: Did you get the following "If there is a specific account that you're going to add users to, the baseUrl will be the same for future users of that account" from documentation?

Assume that a single instance of DocuSign integration in our app always refers to a single DocuSign Account, not user, but Account. Essentially i'm wondering if after the first guy logs in and and get his baseUrl (based on the account Id in question) can all remaining users (of the same DocuSign account) use the same baseUrl or must they get their own?

Comment: To me, it doesn't sound like 2, 10, or 100 different users of the same account will ever have different baseUrl(s).  For that reason if i'm servicing 100 users I need only call login once for any user within that account.  Saving 99 unnecessary calls to login.  All other users can use the same baseUrl retrieved for the account.  If there is a case where two users of the same exact DocuSign account could receive different baseUrls i would like to know how.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's in documentation or not, normally if I know of it I'll link it here. I just know how the structure works for the API and accounts. There is no current way that 2 users on the same account would ever have a different baseUrl. I don't forsee that happening in the future either. A single account resides on a single environment (NA1, NA2, Demo, etc), the users of that account live in that account as well.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to get some outside confirmation on this.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign's [LoginInformation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Login.htm) method enables the implementation to provide dynamic re-direction of the clients at a macro-level.

Currently, or in the future, DocuSign might use the feature for a number of different reasons that I can imagine.

Using an undocumented "feature" (properties of the baseURL result) can result in a brittle client that may fail in the future. Be careful of the siren-song of pre-mature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The baseURL value changes only when you move from different environments (i.e: DEMO vs PROD). I would encourage you to store/cache it yes. Keep in mind when your application is ready for PROD, you will want to get the baseURL for PROD and store/use that appropriately.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.  The fact that service urls differ from production to dev is not of interest.  The question is weather it's possible for two different users in the same DocuSign account to receive different baseUrl(s)?  If the base url is always the same for a given "account" then it's not necessary for me to perform login for every single user that resides in the same account.  It also means i don't need to cache a baseUrl per user.

Comment: "If the base url is always the same for a given "account" then it's not necessary for me to perform login for every single user that resides in the same account. " - i would agree that this is the case.